# Cannot get instrumentable syms in project via Leiningen plugin

Tags: plugins, clojure, specifications, leiningen

I'm trying to write a leiningen plugin based upon `clojure.spec.alpha`. Among other things, I want to get all of the functions in the project that have been spec'd. This is done by calling `instrumentable-syms` in `clojure.spec.test.alpha`. I have a function within my plugin that does this, but when run in the context of another project (via `eval-in-project`), the list of instrumentable syms is empty. I suspect this is because the calls to `fdef` within the project using the plugin, which are generally top-level forms within the source files and which register the specs, are not being evaluated and are thus not being picked up when calling `instrumentable-syms`.

My question is then, how do I make sure these calls get evaluated so my plugin can find all the spec'd functions in a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something to load the relevant namespaces and thus bring your program "to life", perhaps if you have a file like `src/orgname/project/core.clj` then you might try calling:

```
(load "orgname/project/core")
```

From within the block of code run in the project.